# Alternate printing multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my simple code for 2 threads to alternate in printing 2 different numbers. Thread A prints 1 and Thread B prints 2. Both should alternate amongst themselves to print 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,....and so on.
Now I see in the below program we are getting <1,2>,<1,2> combination,...and so on for 5 times only.

Looks like both threads have the same variables which is being shared. But i is a local variable. How it i shared

public class MyThread extends Thread{

```
int numToPrint;
Turn turn;
MyThread(int n, Turn turn)
{
    this.numToPrint=n;
    this.turn=turn;
}
public void run() {
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        if(turn.t==numToPrint) {
            System.out.println(numToPrint);
            if(numToPrint==1)
                turn.t=2;
            else
                turn.t=1;
            turn.doNotify();
        }
        else
        {
           turn.doWait();
        }
    }
}
```

}

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Turn t=new Turn();
    MyThread t1=new MyThread(1,t);
    t1.start();
    MyThread t2=new MyThread(2,t);
    t2.start();

}
```

}